# Greenshot Phoning Home

Tags: networking, connection, open, greenshot

I am trying to trace and close any unnecessary network traffic, and noticed that Greenshot maintains open internet connections.  Nothing in the documentation addresses this.  Is this supposed to happen?  Can it be disabled?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have "Update check interval in days" set to 0?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  No, I cannot find that setting.

Comment: According to https://getgreenshot.org/help/ it should be under general settings

Comment: Found it.  Glad it was not a snake.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Greenshot automatically checks for updates, you can disable them under general settings.

https://getgreenshot.org/help/

> Update check interval in days: Greenshot can check for updates automatically. Use this setting to adjust the
>   interval (in days) or set it to 0 to turn off update checks.